# Mail server on a raspberry pi

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, postfix-mta, mail-server, dovecot

I have searched, but I still don't really understand how to run a mail server on a Raspberry Pi.

Here's my setup for my Pi:

Apache2 hosting multiple sites at one time. So I have virtuals hosts set up, but I'm looking how to run one mail server which can use multiple mails (like info[at]domainA and info[at]domainB.com and so on). I know I'll need to use Postfix and Dovecot, but that's it.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get the information you need, based on just knowing you need Postfix and Dovecot.

You might consider looking at [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=9404) on the forums at raspberrypi.org. It has a number of people running working mail servers on the RaspberryPi and links to the tutorials they used.

You could also try searching Google for ["how to setup postfix and dovecot on debian"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%20to%20setup%20postfix%20and%20dovecot%20on%20debian%22). There are hundreds of tutorials on how to do this with example configurations.

You could also reference the [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html) and [Dovecot](http://wiki.dovecot.org/) documentation, as they also provide information on, not only how to configure the respective pieces of software, but also tutorials and examples of configuration.

There is really no 'silver bullet' solution to setting this up, as it comes down to what you want to get out of it and how you want it to work which, since you don't really have a clearly defined goal, will take some trial and error. Learn by doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but this is a good link.
http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsa-proof-your-e-mail-in-2-hours/